# Bootstrap Tabs Not Working throwing tab undefined error

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the below code to render the bootstrap tab in my MVC application. All the scripts are loaded correctly. but still throwing tab undefined error.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap-tabs.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">
        jhgh
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">
        mbjb
    </div>

</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $('#myTab a').click(function (e) {debugger
            e.preventDefault()
            $(this).tab('show');
        });
    });

</script>
```

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: 1) try without the debugger;
2) Use these markup - http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs
3) check for jQuery conflicts

Comment: thanks.how can i check jquery conflict here ?

Comment: I'm not very sure, I haven't ever use bootstrap, but find this in the docs - 'You can activate a tab or pill navigation without writing any JavaScript by simply specifying data-toggle="tab"'...so try first without your js :)

Comment: if the above doesn't help - give us a simple demo in fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove "debbuger" [WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9Y5PU/7/)

**HTML**

```
<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active">
      <a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
      <a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">
      jhgh
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">
      mbjb
  </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
   $(function () {
        $('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault()
            $(this).tab('show');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should import the complete bootstrap's javascript library, It seems like exists a javascript dependence on bootstraps's files js